# jquery colorbox IE9 error- SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'rel'

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Chrome and Firefox working fine.  Upgraded to latest colorbox and jquery releases, same issue in IE9.

IE9 error message is:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'rel': object is null or undefined 
jquery.colorbox-min.js, line 4 character 1259

(Referred here from the Colorbox FAQ, hope this gets to Jack)

Comment: Retry with the non-minified version of jQuery.colorbox so that we can see where the error is happening. What version of jQuery? 1.9.1?

Answer (score 0):

Kevin, thanks for your advice.

Turns out I thought I had brought the Javascript up to version 1.7.2 and put in the latest colorbox, but I hadn't.  The message "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'rel': object is null or undefined" disappeared when I did get things updated, and all I was left with was IE9 refusing to even open the Colorbox.

I had some extraneous javascript in colorbox_settings.js, intended to remove the IE link styling.  Once I took that out, the functionality of Colorbox in IE9 returned.